# Django migrations, calculate new fields value based on old fields before deleting old fields?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

We are intenting to rework one of our models from old start-end date values to use starting date and length. However, this does pose a challenge in that we want to give default values to our new fields.

In this case, is it possible to run migration where we create new field, give it a value based on models old start-end fields

```py
from datetime import date as Date
from django.db import models
    
class Period(models.Model):
    
    #These are our new fields to replace old fields
    period_length=models.IntegerField(default=12)
    starting_date=models.DateField(default=Date.today)
    
    #Old fields. We want to calculate the period length based on these before we remove them
    start_day = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    start_month = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    end_day = models.IntegerField(default=31)
    end_month = models.IntegerField(default=12)
```

Starting months and ending months can be anywhere between 1 and 12, so we need to run bunch of calculations to get the correct length. Is there a way for us to run a function in migrations that, after adding the new fields, calculates their new values before calling for removal of the old fields?

I do know I can create basic add/remove fields with makemigrations, but I want to add the value calculations in between. Other option I have considered is to first run a migration to add the fields, then a custom command to calculate fields and then a second migration that deletes the old fields, but this feels like it has greater chance of breaking something.

Comment: A DateField includes a year but you haven't been storing years, where will you get the year from?

Comment: Year is relatively unimportant. Old system assumed assumed concrete periods which had certain start and end dates for each year. However, since then I have been informed we might have 18 month long periods, which is not viable in the old system.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What I would do is create a custom migration and define the following series of operations there:

1. Add length field.
2. Update length field with calculations.
3. Remove old field.

So you can create a custom migration with:

```
python manage.py makemigrations --name migration_name app_name --empty
```

And then define there the series of operations you need:

```
operations = [
         migrations.AddField (... your length field...),
         migrations.RunPython (... the name of your function to compute and store length field ...),
         migrations.RemoveField (... your end_date field ...),
     ]
```

Edit:

Your migration should be something as below (*update_length_field* would be your function, with the same parameters):

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('app_name', 'your_previous_migration'),
    ]

    def update_length_field(apps, schema_editor):
        for period in Period.objects.all():
            period.length = ... whatever calculations you need ...
            period.save()

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField (... your length field...),
        migrations.RunPython(update_length_field),
        migrations.RemoveField (... your end_date field ...),
    ]
```

At a basic level, it would be like this.

Now, if you want the migration to be able to be rolled back, you will have to define a second function that does exactly the opposite of what *update_length_field* does. And put it as the second parameter of *migrations.RunPython*.

Also, if you want the migration to be compatible with future changes to the model (this is not necessary if the migration is to be deployed only once), you must take the model from the historical version of the code, something like:

```
    def update_length_field(apps, schema_editor):
        Period = apps.get_model("app_name", "Period")
        for period in Period.objects.all():
            period.length = ...
            period.save()
```

More information here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/migration-operations/

Comment: This seems pretty close to what I am looking for. Do I need to specify parameters for RunPython, or just pass the name of the function directly? Also, will this run said function per item in database, or do I need to conduct query myself?

Comment: Edited. Although I am not sure I have understood your second question.

Comment: Your example answers my question perfectly. I need to conduct query in the function and save each instance of the model. I ran migration on my local SQLite database and it worked. Thank you for your help!